# Update CustomListViewAdapter when new data is added android

Tags: android, xmpp

i have a chat base application and when i receive message from user my CustomListViewAdapter is not updated. i have alrady used adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but it does not work in my case. here is my code

```
public class Messages extends Activity implements
     OnItemClickListener{

private RowItem item;
ListView listView;
public static List<RowItem> rowItems;
private CustomListViewAdapter adapter; 
//private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList();


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub\     
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages,null);
        return view;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.messages);



    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    item = new RowItem(R.drawable.messages, "messages");
    rowItems.add(item);
    adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
    final EditText msg1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msg);
    Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(msg1.getText().toString().equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "type message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else
            { 
            String to = "asghar@web.vlivetech.com";
            String text = msg1.getText().toString();
            msg1.setText("");
            Log.i("XMPPClient", "Sending text [" + text + "] to [" + to + "]");
            Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
            msg.setBody(text);
            Network.connection.sendPacket(msg);
            //messages.add(Network.connection.getUser() + ":");
            //messages.add(text);
            item = new RowItem(R.drawable.connection, text);
            rowItems.add(item);
            adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                    R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            //setListAdapter();
            }
        }
    });

    PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
    Network.connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
            Message message = (Message) packet;
            if (message.getBody() != null) {
                String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
                Log.i("XMPPClient", "Got text [" + message.getBody() + "] from [" + fromName + "]");
               //recieve.setText(message.getBody());
                /*messages.add(fromName + ":");
                messages.add(message.getBody());*/
                // Add the incoming message to the list view
                item = new RowItem(R.drawable.billing, message.getBody());
                adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                        R.layout.list_item, rowItems);

                rowItems.add(item);
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }, filter);

    PacketFilter filter1 = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.headline);
    Network.connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
            Message message = (Message) packet;
            if (message.getBody() != null) {
                String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
                Log.i("XMPPClient", "Got text wth xml [" + message.toXML() + "] from [" + fromName + "]");
               //recieve.setText(message.getBody());
                /*messages.add(fromName + ":");
                messages.add(message.getBody());*/
                 // Add the incoming message to the list view

                item = new RowItem(R.drawable.billing, message.getBody());
                adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                        R.layout.list_item, rowItems);                 
                rowItems.add(item);
                //adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }, filter1);

    //listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.messages, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this code if it works i will say why:

```
public class Messages extends Activity implements
OnItemClickListener{

private RowItem item;
ListView listView;
public static List<RowItem> rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
private CustomListViewAdapter adapter; 
//private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.messages);




    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    item = new RowItem(R.drawable.messages, "messages");
    rowItems.add(item);
    adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
    final EditText msg1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msg);
    Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(msg1.getText().toString().equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "type message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else
            { 
            String to = "asghar@web.vlivetech.com";
            String text = msg1.getText().toString();
            msg1.setText("");
            Log.i("XMPPClient", "Sending text [" + text + "] to [" + to + "]");
            Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
            msg.setBody(text);
            Network.connection.sendPacket(msg);
            //messages.add(Network.connection.getUser() + ":");
            //messages.add(text);
            item = new RowItem(R.drawable.connection, text);
            rowItems.add(item);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });

    PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
    Network.connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
            Message message = (Message) packet;
            if (message.getBody() != null) {
                String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
                Log.i("XMPPClient", "Got text [" + message.getBody() + "] from [" + fromName + "]");
               //recieve.setText(message.getBody());
                /*messages.add(fromName + ":");
                messages.add(message.getBody());*/
                // Add the incoming message to the list view
                item = new RowItem(R.drawable.billing, message.getBody());
                rowItems.add(item);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
    }, filter);

    PacketFilter filter1 = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.headline);
    Network.connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
            Message message = (Message) packet;
            if (message.getBody() != null) {
                String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
                Log.i("XMPPClient", "Got text wth xml [" + message.toXML() + "] from [" + fromName + "]");
               //recieve.setText(message.getBody());
                /*messages.add(fromName + ":");
                messages.add(message.getBody());*/
                 // Add the incoming message to the list view

                item = new RowItem(R.drawable.billing, message.getBody());                
                rowItems.add(item);
                adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

            }
        }
    }, filter1);

}
```

Comment: rowItems.add(item); this is the Massage.java line 70

Comment: is it in a onClick listener or in a onCreate

Comment: do you exactly copy and paste it, i wonder why because rowItems has been initialized

Comment: it is in a onCreate @mmlooloo

Comment: how could i update my CustomListView in on crate using thread will tell me

Comment: i have copied and past the exact code my listview shows nothing

Comment: you must ask it on SO it is hard for me to tell it without any codes. ask on SO to get fast help. i am going out now and will check it after come back.

Comment: no u just tell me how could i update my adapter in a runnable thread in on create: so my adapter is automatically updated... and what is SO?

Comment: SO= stack overflow , use `runOnUiThread` search for usage. if you used asynctask you can do another way look at this to see how many ways you can do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451577/how-to-deal-with-asynctask-with-ui-thread-in-the-do-while-situation/25451833#25451833

Comment: i have tried ur code but it does not show message when i recieved message from another user. but when i send message from my appllication it will show received message after sending message from my application